# How To Prevent Admin-Ajax.php in Wordpress from crashing server?

Tags: wordpress

So my 2GB RAM Linode machine keeps going out of memory and crashing randomly once or twice per day and I could never diagnose what the problem was. I just have a few low traffic Wordpress/Woocommerce sites and they handle even large traffic fine.

I found a way to replicate the problem finally. All I needed to do was go to my shop page, press the Add to Cart button repeatedly on different products (and they use Ajax to add to cart within the page) and if I did it fast enough there would be like a bunch of admin-ajax.php calls being generated (each using like 5% of memory) and also some wp-cron.php would start popping up. The server would then go out and have a oom killer and I would need to restart mysql or server.

Here are mysql settings in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
open_files_limit=1024000
max_connections=75
key_buffer=32M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
thread_stack=128K
table_cache=32
innodb_buffer_pool_size=800M
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
query_cache_size=8M
tmp_table_size=16M
max_heap_table_size=16M
thread_cache_size=4
table_open_cache=32
```

And here is apache settings in httpd.ini:

```
Starts Servers 2 
Minimum Spare Servers 6 
Maximum Spare Servers 12 
Server Limit 256 
Max Clients 50 
Max Requests Per Child 3000 
Keep-Alive Off
```

Is there something I can change here to prevent this? Server shouldn't go down on just one person goofing around adding products to cart should it?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix one problem (wp-cron.php) by following the below steps:

Add the following line in your wp-config.php file after your database details (after define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”) line):

define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');

wp-cron.php is WordPress virtual cron and this file will be called whenever your blog post or blog is being accessed. If you are using cron for your WordPress, you should use other plugin or set up a cronjob from your control panel.